# GDB TUI mode not showing breakpoints

Tags: debugging, gdb, tui

Even when I start GDB with `--nx` to ensure no configuration file is messing something up somewhere, the TUI mode simply does not display breakpoints.

I enable TUI mode via the `--tui` CLI flag, and then set breakpoints using `break <line number>`.

According to documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Overview.html#TUI-Overview), set breakpoints should simply always be visible next to the source code, as either a lower- or uppercase letter "B", followed by either a "+" or "-" to indicate whether or not the breakpoint is active. The source code, by the way, is displayed normally without issues. But try as I might, no matter how many breakpoints I set, they are never shown.

Execution does stop at breakpoints normally. So this isn't some horrible issue that completely breaks GDB, but it would be rather nice to be able to see which breakpoints I've set and what their state is, next to the code.